# Append element in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, append

I have a menu in html code witch I append it inside an element (created in ng-repeat) when the user click on it, and I am removing the menu if the user click outside of the element.
The problem is, that the new menu that I am inserting inside the element does not know the current item in the repeat.. its does calling the function in the scope, but when I passing the current item as a argument its passing undefined.

Here how I am included the menu:

```
    $scope.openFileMenu = function (item) {
    var id = "#file-item-" + item.f_id;
    if ($(id).find(".filemenu").length > 0)
        return;
    $(".filemenu").remove();
    $(id).prepend($compile("<div class='filemenu' ng-include=\"'views/common/file_tools.html'\"></div>")($scope));
    $(document).one('click', function closeMenu(e) {
        if ($(id).has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(id).find(".filemenu").remove();
        } else {
            $(document).one('click', closeMenu);
        }
    });
}
```

Here the repeat code:

```
                    <div class="file-box animated fadeInDown" ng-repeat="item in files" ng-init="">
                    <div class="file" id="file-item-{{item.f_id}}">
                        <a href="" ng-click="openFileMenu(item)">
                           .......... file details.......
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So every time the user click on the item the menu will open (the menu html file just have an ul element)

Than, there is deleteFile function, witch being called from the html menu file from one of the li

```
    $scope.deleteFile = function (item) {
    alert(item);
    var url = "handlers/FilesService.asmx/deleteFile";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify({ f_id: item.f_id }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        }
    });
}
```

***But the argument in deleteFile function will always be undefined.***

This is the html file that I am including:

```
<ul>
<li tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="download"><i class="fa fa-download fa-lg"></i></li>
<li tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="delete" class="red" ng-click="deleteFile(item)"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></li>
```